# TinyMCE issue in pasting the content from MSword-2010. No line break is seen if pasted directly

Tags: php, tinymce, line-breaks, content-editor

I am using tinyMCE for pasting description on front end of the site. Issue I am having is - when I try to paste the content taken out directly from MS Word 2010 I am not able to see the same line spacing as on word document.

I have uploaded 3 images showing the document and content when pasted into the editor and the content displayed after getting post.

[image: wordDocument-2010-content]

[image: ContentInsideEditor]

[image: ContentAfterPost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is you would need to set the editor width to exactly the same width of a Word 2010 page. In Word you may change the margins whcih will lead to another problem.
Another point is the font. You will need to apply the same font and same font-size in the editor (you may use the config param content_css for this).

Comment: I got a good clue. The posted data is getting stripped and it is causing the issue. `$compDesc = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>/', '', $compDesc); // Remove the start <p> or <p attr="">        
     $compDesc = preg_replace('/<\/p>/', '<br/>', $compDesc); // Replace the end`
above are the 2 lines and how would it affect if I remove those 2 lines.